# How does one repoint an SSAS project to a server instead of local workation

Tags: visual-studio-2010, ssas, cube

I am running Visual Studio 2010, SQL Server 2012.  I created a Analysis Cube project in Visual Studio.  When I go to deploy I receive the following error.

"Either the 'DOMAIN\User' user does not have permission to create a new object in 'MyLocalWorksationName' or the object does not exist.

I've added my domain on SSAS and even tried creating a blank SSAS database with the matching name and the problem looks to me like when I go to deploy for the first time its trying to deploy to my local workstation.  If that is the case, how to I get Visual Studio to deploy to SSAS instead?

Comment: Correction.  How do I deploy the Cube to the SQL Server instead of locally to my machine?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have exactly the same version of VS as you, so YMMV a bit, but here's the setting:

- Right-click on the Project (top-level object) in the Solution Explorer.
- Select "Properties"
- Find the "Deployment" section
- There should be a section called "Target", specifying a servername and database name.